# How to update a brach on which a Pull request has already been made

Tags: git, git-merge, rebase, pull-request

I have made Pull Requests for "branchA" and "branchB" which is diverged from my local-develop branch.
My PR - branchA got merged to origin-develop.
I was requested to make some changes on "branchB" after code review.
What should I do to get the changes from origin-develop on branchA before making the requested changes?

What I did was -

`git checkout develop
 git pull origin-develop
 git checkout branchA
 git rebase develop`

And as you thought I messed it up, but I renamed "branchA" to "branchA-updated" and gonna make a new PR from there.

What should be the ideal workflow in these case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a PR is made, it doesn't mean that you cant push to the branch you want to merge. In this case, you should've merged whatever was on branch develop to your branchB:

1. `git checkout branchB`

Situational step: `git pull origin branchB` (to update your local branchB with whatever is in remote branchB. Mostly needed when multiple developers are pushing to branchB.)

2. `git pull origin develop` to apply remote develop changes into local branchB (this step can be done with rebase as well, it depends mostly on the project's git policy.)
3. `git push origin branchB` to push local changes from local branchB to remote branchB (therefore, updating the PR)